# How to ICO for tokens based on Stellar blockchain?

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-laboratory, stellar-website, ico

How an ICO can be initiated? Shall we write a smart contract for it like in ETH network?

We want to have the following parameters on our ICO:

Token rate, hard/soft cap tokens, start/end date, minimum investment, the number of tokens offered on the ICO as well as the ability to withdraw before the completion of the ICO.

Is this possible for tokens based on Stellar?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily [issue a new token on Stellar](https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar?locale=en) but managing an ICO is a different story and won't work on chain.